# Autograd Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, autograd

I am new to pytorch, and I have been trying some examples with autograd, to see if I understand it. I am confused about why the following code does not work:

```
def Loss(a):
  return a**2

a=torch.tensor(3.0, requires_grad=True )
L=Loss(a)
L.backward()
with torch.no_grad(): a=a+1.0
L=Loss(a)
L.backward()
print(a.grad)
```

Instead of outputing 8.0, we get "RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn"

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to note regarding your code:

1. You are performing two back propagation up to leaf `a` which means the gradients should accumulate. In other words, you should get a gradient equal to `da²/da + d(a+1)²/da` which is equal to `2a + 2(a+1)` which is `2(2a + 1)`. If `a=3`, then a.grad will be equal to `14`.
2. You are using a `torch.no_grad` context manager which means you will be unable to perform backpropagation from any resulting tensor *i.e.* here `a` itself.

Here is a snippet which yields the desired result, that is `14` as the accumulation of both gradients:

```
>>> L = Loss(a)
>>> L.backward()
>>> a.grad
6

>>> L = Loss(a+1)
>>> L.backward()
>>> a.grad
14 # as 6 + 8
```